# Modifying React style object seems to corrupt dom styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm pretty sure I found a React bug but I want to post the question here before submitting an issue on Github.

I'll link to a reduced test case, but here's the data flow:

1. You have a React component, and it has a `style={this.state.style}` attribute assigned to it.
2. You `setState` so that the style object is now

   ```
   style={
     border: "1px solid red"
   }
   ```
3. You `setState` to add a `borderColor` to this style property

   ```
   style={
     border: "1px solid red"
     borderColor: "blue"
   }
   ```
4. Later on, you `setState` to remove the `borderColor`

   ```
   style={
     border: "1px solid red"
   }
   ```

What happens if you do this? Well, your border turns black. If you inspect the DOM to see the styles applied to your element, it will look like this:

```
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-image: initial;
```

Needless to say, this is not what I expect to happen. It seems that React is doing some kind of DOM style-translation and it's not behaving appropriately. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/danielvaughn/pen/jeqqKV) with a reduced test case demonstrating the behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a React bug, unfortunately.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6348

The tl;dr is that when removing the borderColor style, React does effectively `node.style.borderColor = ''` to unset it, but this cancels out some of the style from the `border` shorthand property. Hopefully we'll get it fixed someday.

A workaround, as Andrew said, is to set the properties individually.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting issue. All I can say is that I have solved your issue by explicitly setting the border color, width, and style. Then toggling it based on it's value. Here's a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/asteinheiser/pen/MPyeEB).

```
var Test = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      styles: {
        borderWidth: '10px',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderColor: 'red'
      }
    }
  },

  toggle: function() {
    this.setState(function(prevState) {
      var styles = prevState.styles

      if (styles.borderColor === 'red') {
        styles.borderColor = 'blue'
      } else {
        styles.borderColor = 'red'
      }

      console.log('new styles:')
      console.log( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(styles) ) )

      return {
        styles: styles
      }
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div
        className="test"
        style={this.state.styles}
        onClick={this.toggle}
      >
        click me
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Interesting, so it does seem to have something to do with shorthand declarations. Maybe React tries to do some fancy logic and we end up with this garbled result?

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that when it has a controlled `border-color` prop, then you delete it, `react` assumes that you want it to be `unset`. I think it deconstructs your shorthand on initial load, then when you delete the color, it has no fallbacks.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer unless someone else wants to offer a more in-depth explanation.